# How to load data from API to input fields?

Tags: angular

I would like to make a "user profile" page. It should load all of the data of the registered user to input fields (if the data exists). Then everyone can edit these (or add new ones). The first step would be to load the data to the specific input fields. I sucessfully make a `GET` request (everything is good in the console), but the input fields remain empty.

The page after `Get` request:
[image: how it looks like]

The component:

```
getData() {
    this.apiService.getUser(this.id, this.email, this.password).subscribe(
      (user) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.bankArray.push(user.banks);
      },
    );
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let obj of user.personal">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Title"
          name="title"
          [(ngModel)]="obj.title"
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Forename"
          name="foreName"
          [(ngModel)]="obj.foreName"
        /><br />
    </div>

    <h3>Financial</h3>
    <button (click)="addNewBank()">+</button>
    <div *ngFor="let obj of bankArray; let i = index">
      <button (click)="removeBank(i)">-</button>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Bank name"
        name="bankName{{ i }}"
        [(ngModel)]="obj.bankName"
      /><br />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="IBAN"
        name="iban{{ i }}"
        [(ngModel)]="obj.iban"
      /><br />
</form>
```

The Console log(user):
[image]

Comment: are u taking response from api?

Comment: Yes, I am taking.

Comment: in get data u are assigning to user but in ngModel u want to take from personal ? What is personal

Comment: I am sorry, I have updated the code. The personal is an array of user.

Comment: I assume that you are already doing this, but I said that it's better to ask. Do you call the getData() method from somewhere, like ngOnInitMethod() ?

Comment: Of course. First of all there are 2 fields for (email + password) then the submit button calls the method.

Comment: then write obj.title rather than personel.title

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to edit them too. Still not working... Just the empty fields.

Comment: can you console. this user and take image and share too ?

Comment: I have updated the question. I know that personal is `null`. This is because of a bug. But the banks arte good and they should appear under "financial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed that you are pushing the **banks** details into **bankArray** from response.

Since **banks** is an array of elements you cannot directly push whole array into **bankArray**, you have to iterate/loop the banks and insert one by one into **bankArray**

Here is the updated code,

```
getData() {
this.apiService.getUser(this.id, this.email, this.password).subscribe(
  (user) => {
    this.user = user;
    user.banks.forEach(bank => {
         this.bankArray.push(bank);   
    });
  },
);
```

}

And regarding **personal** data, if you see **Console Log** which you have attached **personal** data is **null**

Comment: Thank you! Exactly this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening, you html is not updating after getting response from API

You should use `*ngIf` to make sure html is updated after getting response from API

```
<ng-container *ngIf="bankArray.length">
  <div *ngFor="let obj of bankArray; let i = index">
    <button (click)="removeBank(i)">-</button>
    <br />
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Bank name"
      name="bankName{{ i }}"
      [(ngModel)]="obj.bankName"
    /><br />
    <input
      type="number"
      placeholder="IBAN"
      name="iban{{ i }}"
      [(ngModel)]="obj.iban"
    /><br />
   </div>
 </ng-container>
```